# Want create zendframework/skeleton-application project, but not last version

Tags: windows, zend-framework, zend-framework2, composer-php

I'm trying to create a new zend framework project with version 2.4 by composer.

How can I do it?

I tried this:

```
$ composer create-project zendframework/skeleton-application project-name 2.4
```

But I had this error:

```
Could not find package zendframework/skeleton-application with version 2.4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Packagist [doesn't have version 2.4 of `zendframework/skeleton-application`](https://packagist.org/packages/zendframework/skeleton-application). That is probably because [it doesn't appear to exist](https://github.com/zendframework/ZendSkeletonApplication/tags). (The framework itself [does have a 2.4 version](https://github.com/zendframework/zendframework/releases), but that's not the same thing.)

You should be able to install version 2.3 or 2.5, though.